# remove specific line from a file in php

Tags: php, file

I've a file called "test.php". Content of this file will be more similar to the following:

```
<?php
require_once "classes/xconfig.php";
require_once "Facebook/index.php";
require_once "classes/class.uvlogin.php";
?>
```

**Edit:** Based on user's choice i want to remove some configurations found in this test.php.
for example, if the user doesn't want automated configurations the i've to remove `require_once "classes/xconfig.php";` from the file.

Is it possible to remove/overwrite specific line of a file.

Comment: You mean other than using a text editor?

Comment: Highlight that line and press `Delete`. If I was serious I don't really understand what you mean by removing. Using what and when are you going to remove?

Comment: @All:Think i make you understand the question in a wrong way. I've updated my question, check the edit block.

Comment: Why would you want to remove a piece of the code, based on an individual users preference, when that code is going to effect every single user on the site? Why are you not looking at only loading the required file *via code* (i.e. an `if` statement) instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Based on user's choice i want to remove some configurations found in this test.php. for example, if the user doesn't want automated configurations the i've to remove require_once "classes/xconfig.php"; from the file.

PHP is a programming language. This means that you can have dynamic stuff. This means that it shouldn't be all too hard to figure this one out; just use an if-statement.

```
<?php
if( $user_wants_xconfig ) { require_once "classes/xconfig.php"; }
if( $user_wants_facebook ) { require_once "Facebook/index.php"; }
if( $user_wants_uvlogin ) { require_once "classes/class.uvlogin.php"; }
```

Comment: The issue here is, this test.php exists already, based on the options selected by the user , the lines in the file modified as i said above and given to the user. so the test.php is going to be used by end user.

Comment: @Sekar For your requirements this is great solution. if you do what you want, you have to copy test.php for every user and then modify it, because you'll have it just once it will be modified for others too. I am kinda confused.

Comment: @PLB: I got it. This solution doesn't suits me, but i got way to resolve it. It goes like this, if the user wants facebook login also if facebook directory exists in the downloadable list then include it. thats it. Thanks Berry,PLB and all. I'm not presented this question well, so this confusion...